# How to use spring transaction rollback?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, transactional

I'm working on spring boot project where I'm using JPA (postgres as database). I want to make a bunch of insert in database using spring transaction.

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {}
```

As I add "@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)", I expect that jpa will use the same transaction for the 10 persist operations and  rollback when the error is thrown (the table of the entity "Foo" will stay empty). However, I see 5 rows added. What I'm missing here ?
This is my service class:

```
@Service
public class TransactServiceImpl implements TransactService {

@Autowired
FooRepository fooRepository;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void test() {
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Foo f = new Foo ("foo " + i);
            fooRepository.save(f);
            if (i == 5)throw new RuntimeException("Rollback this transaction!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, you're throwing and catching the exception. So it's basically as if you did nothing. Don't catch the exception.

Comment: I remove the catch block and it worked. But the execption is thrown and not handled, it will break the whole app. Should I handle the execption outside the metod "test" ?

Comment: Spring will rollback if a runtime exception is thrown by a transactional method. If nothing is being thrown, then no rollback will happen. If you want to programmatically rollback, without throwing an exception, then call `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()`. Exceptions are typically caught where you can do something useful with them: in the UI layer, where you can display an error message.

Comment: A transaction should be seen as an "atomic" operation performing some business logic. Your business logic says "persist 10 items", if there is an error, rollback everything as if nothing happened. What needs to be done if there is an error? Will you try the operation "persist 10 items" again, will you display an error message or do you just don't care? This decision can only be made outside of the actual operation.
So yes, you should handle the execption outside the metod "test". If you catch it inside, the operation "persist 10 items" will return successfully (though it only peristed 5).